# How can i resolve the issue: Signet::AuthorizationError: Authorization failed. Server message while creating event using Google calender API in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-client

I want to integrate google calendar api in my rails project to generate events to set meetings. I have not installed oauth 2 gem since i am using different aunthentication system for my application and pundit for authorization.

**GemFile**

```
ruby '3.1.2'

gem 'active_model_serializers'
gem 'active_storage_validations'
gem 'rails', '6.1.3.2'

gem 'bootsnap', require: false
gem 'debug', platforms: %i[mri mingw x64_mingw]
gem 'dotenv-rails'
gem 'google-api-client'
gem 'http_accept_language'
gem 'importmap-rails'
gem 'jbuilder'
gem 'jwt'
gem 'mini_magick', '>= 4.9.5'
gem 'mjml-rails'
gem 'mongoid'
gem 'mongoid_search'
gem 'net-imap', require: false
gem 'net-pop', require: false
gem 'net-smtp', require: false
gem 'pagy'
gem 'pg', '~> 1.1'
gem 'phony_rails'
gem 'psych', '< 4'
gem 'puma', '~> 5.0'
gem 'pundit', '~> 2.2'
gem 'rack-cors'
gem 'ros-apartment', require: 'apartment'
gem 'sassc-rails'
gem 'sprockets-rails'
gem 'stimulus-rails'
gem 'turbo-rails'
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: %i[mingw mswin x64_mingw jruby]
gem 'whenever'
```

This is my code.

**app/controllers/api/v1/interviews_controller.rb**

```
module Api
  module V1
    class InterviewsController < BaseController
      include ParamsSanitizer
      before_action :interview, only: %i[show update destroy index]

      def create
        # authorize(:interview, :create?)
        command('create_interview', { params: create_params })
      end
    end
  end
end
```

the workflow to create the interview and meet link for the interview:

**app/workflows/interviews/create.rb**

```
# frozen_string_literal: true
require 'google/apis/calendar_v3'
require 'googleauth'
require 'googleauth/stores/file_token_store'

module Interviews
  class Create < Base
    attr_accessor :applicant, :interview, :current_user

    flow_as :create_interview

    def run
      @interview = ::Interview.create!(params)
      @applicant = Applicant.includes(:interviews, :vacancy).where(id: interview.applicant_id)

      if @interview.interview_type == 'online'
        generate_meet_link
        InterviewMailer.new_online_interview_email(@applicant, @interview).deliver_now
      else
        InterviewMailer.new_onsite_interview_email(@applicant, @interview).deliver_now
      end
      run_write_hooks
    end

    def additional_resource
      { record: @interview }
    end

    def generate_meet_link
      calendar = GoogleCalendar.new(current_user)
      start_time = Time.now + 1.hour
      end_time = start_time + 1.hour
      # Create an array of EventAttendee objects for each attendee

      attendees = JSON.parse(attendee_emails.map { |email| Google::Apis::CalendarV3::EventAttendee.new(email: email) }.to_json)
      # Create an event in Google Calendar
      event = calendar.create_event('My Meeting', start_time, end_time, attendees)

      # Generate a Google Meet link for the event
      google_meet_link = calendar.generate_google_meet_link(event.id)

      @interview.assign_attributes!(meet_link: google_meet_link, start_time: start_time, end_time: end_time)
    end

    def attendee_emails
      User.joins(:team_members).where(team_members: { team_id: @interview.vacancy.team_id }).pluck(:email)
    end
  end
end
```

**app/lib/google_calendar.rb**

```
require 'google/apis/calendar_v3'
require 'google/api_client/client_secrets'
require 'googleauth'

class GoogleCalendar
  def initialize(current_user)
    # refresh_token = current_user.refresh_token

    authorization = Google::Auth::UserRefreshCredentials.new(
      # client_id: secrets.client_id,
      # client_secret: secrets.client_secret
      #   redirect_uri: secrets.redirect_uri,
      #   refresh_token: secrets.refresh_token
      client_id: ENV.fetch('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID', nil),
      client_secret: ENV.fetch('GOOGLE_client_secret', nil),
      #redirect_uri: ENV.fetch('REQUEST_URI', nil),
      # refresh_token: refresh_token
    )
  end

  def create_event(_summary, _start_time, _end_time, _attendee_emails)
    event = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::Event.new(
      summary: 'My Meeting',
      start: {
        date_time: _start_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'),
        time_zone: 'UTC'
      },
      end: {
        date_time: _end_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'),
        time_zone: 'UTC'
      },
      attendees: _attendee_emails,
      conference_data: {
        create_request: {
          request_id: 'random-request-id' # You can provide any random string as the request ID
        }
      }
    )

    @calendar.insert_event('primary', event)
  end

  def generate_google_meet_link(event_id)
    conference = @calendar.get_event_conference('primary', event_id)
    conference?.conference_solution?.url
  end
end
```

Now My question is, what is the process to setup the refresh_token and redirect_uri and how to solve the error while running the method:

```
[1] pry(#<Interviews::Create>)> calendar.create_event('My Meeting', start_time, end_time, attendees)
Signet::AuthorizationError: Authorization failed.  Server message:
{
  "error": "unsupported_grant_type",
  "error_description": "Invalid grant_type: "
}
from /Users/rabeyakhatunmuna/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/signet-0.17.0/lib/signet/oauth_2/client.rb:1028:in `fetch_access_token'
```